# Execute StableBaselines3 training on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, torch, stable-baselines

I am trying to train a Stable Baselines 3 PPO Reinforcement Learning Agent using GPU to accelerate the process, but when I run my training, I get this error:

```
  File "/src/train_V1_agents.py", line 67, in <module>
    runTrainingExecution(agent_name_index = agent)
  File "src/train_V1_agents.py", line 45, in runTrainingExecution
    agent.train_agent(n_steps = n_steps, total_timesteps = total_timesteps, callback=None, log_interval=1, tb_log_name=tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps=True, progress_bar=True)
  File "/src/AI/Agents/RLAgent.py", line 248, in train_agent
    mean_reward = self.evaluate()
  File "/src/AI/Agents/RLAgent.py", line 169, in evaluate
    mean_reward, std_reward = evaluate_policy(self.model, self.gym_env, n_eval_episodes=self.n_eval_episodes,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/common/evaluation.py", line 84, in evaluate_policy
    observations = env.reset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py", line 87, in reset
    self._save_obs(env_idx, obs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py", line 114, in _save_obs
    self.buf_obs[key][env_idx] = obs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 972, in __array__
    return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

From what I understand, the error suggests that I should copy the tensor to the CPU, but I guess that, if I do that, the training will not be performed in the GPU, which is what I am aiming. Therefore, I'd like to know how I can prevent this error from happening by also assuring the execution will be done using the GPU to accelerate the process?

This is my code for the agent:

```
class Agent(BaseAlgorithm):
    def __init__(self, gym_env, model_name = "ppo-domtree-v1-PPO", model_type = PPO, policy_string = "MlpPolicy", n_steps = 1024, batch_size = 64, n_epochs = 4, gamma = 0.999, gae_lambda = 0.98, ent_coef = 0.01, verbose = 1, learning_rate = 3e-4, n_eval_episodes = 10, 
        log_dir = "./gym_logs/"):

        # Initialization of other parameters....
        # Move agent to GPU
        self.device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

    def learn(self, total_timesteps, load_if_previous = False, training_step = 0, checkpoint_interval=100, callback=None, log_interval=1, tb_log_name='AgentV1',
            reset_num_timesteps=True, progress_bar=True):
        # Set the model's environment before training
        self.model.set_env(self.gym_env)

        current_step = 0
        final_model_name = f"{self.model_path}_{training_step}_final"

        # Check if the model already exists
        if os.path.exists(f"{final_model_name}.zip") and load_if_previous:
            print(f"\tModel for training step {training_step} already exists ({final_model_name}.zip). Loading the model.")
        else:
            while current_step < total_timesteps:
                remaining_steps = total_timesteps - current_step
                steps_to_train = min(checkpoint_interval, remaining_steps)

                # Check if the model already exists
                iternmediate_model_file = f"{self.model_path}_{training_step}_{current_step}.zip"
                print(f"\t\t Finding {iternmediate_model_file}...")
                if os.path.exists(iternmediate_model_file) and load_if_previous:
                    print(f"\t\t Model for training step and batch {training_step} already exists ({iternmediate_model_file}.zip). Loading the model")
                    self.load(iternmediate_model_file)
                else:
                    print(f"\t\t Learning batch # {current_step}")
                    self.model.set_env(self.gym_env)
                    self.model.learn(total_timesteps=steps_to_train, callback=callback, log_interval=log_interval,
                                    tb_log_name=tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar=progress_bar)

                    # Save the model after every checkpoint interval
                    if current_step % checkpoint_interval == 0:
                        self.save(f"{self.model_path}_{training_step}_{current_step}")

                current_step += steps_to_train

            # Save the final model
            self.save(final_model_name)
        return self.load(f"{final_model_name}.zip")

   # Other non relevant functions ...
    
    def train_agent(self, n_steps = 2048, total_timesteps = 50000, callback=None, log_interval=1, tb_log_name='AgentV1', reset_num_timesteps=True, progress_bar=False, checkpoint = True):
        base_path =  f"{self.model_path}_{total_timesteps}_{n_steps}_"
        extension = ".zip"
        mean_reward = 0

        # train the agent
        # Loading the last training info to continue from the same point in case the execution ends abruptly
        if checkpoint:
            best_mean_reward, best_model_path = -float('inf'), None
            model_paths =  glob.glob(f"{base_path}_*{extension}")
            # Check if there is a saved model
            if model_paths:
                best_model_path = max(model_paths, key=lambda path: int(path.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]))
                print("Loading saved model...")
                self.load(best_model_path)
                last_step = int(best_model_path.split("_")[-1].split('.')[0])
                print(f"Continuing training from step #{last_step}")
            else:
                last_step = 0

        best_mean_reward, best_model_path = -float('inf'), None
        for i in range(1, n_steps+1):
            print(f"\n_______________________________________________________________Training step #{i}/{n_steps}_______________________________________________________________", flush=True)
            self.gym_env.reset()
            print(f"\tIterations for the step: {total_timesteps}", flush=True)
            self.gym_env.test_case = data_wrapper.insert("Test_cases", {
                "Execution_uid": self.gym_env.execution['uid'],
                "Initial_time": utils.getDateTime(),
                "Error_count": 0
            })
            self.learn(total_timesteps=total_timesteps, load_if_previous = True, training_step = i)
            # evaluate the agent and log the results
            mean_reward = self.evaluate()
            if mean_reward > best_mean_reward:
                best_mean_reward = mean_reward
                best_model_path = f"{base_path}_{i}{extension}"
                self.save(best_model_path)
                print(f"\tNew best model saved to {best_model_path}")
                print(f"\tNew best model saved to {best_model_path}", flush=True)   
            data_wrapper.update("Test_cases", {"uid": self.gym_env.test_case['uid'] }, { "$set":  self.gym_env.test_case })

            print(f"\n_________________________________________ Training step #{i}/{n_steps} ended at: {datetime.datetime.now()} _________________________________________\n\n\n", flush=True)
        
        # SAFE THE FINAL MODEL
        self.save(self.model_path)
        try:
            print("Generating plot to send...")
            # Call plot_results and redirect the output to a StringIO object
            results_plotter.plot_results([ self.log_dir], 100, results_plotter.X_TIMESTEPS, tb_log_name)

            # Capture the plot
            fig = plt.gcf()

            # Save the figure to a file
            plot_file = f"training_results_{ str(int(time.time())) }.png"
            # Save the plot to a file
            fig.savefig(plot_file)

            print(f"Plot saved at {plot_file}")
            plt.close(fig)  # Close the plot to free up memory
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error when generating the plot with the built in function")
            print(e) 
            plot_file = ''
        utils.sendTrainingEndEmail(tb_log_name, mean_reward, plot_file, self.gym_env.test_case)
        
class PPOAgent(Agent):
    def _setup_model(self):
        self.model = PPO(policy=self.policy_string,
                            env=self.gym_env,
                            learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
                            n_steps=self.n_steps,
                            batch_size=self.batch_size,
                            n_epochs=self.n_epochs,
                            gamma=self.gamma,
                            gae_lambda=self.gae_lambda,
                            clip_range=0.2, 
                            clip_range_vf=None, 
                            normalize_advantage=True,
                            ent_coef=self.ent_coef,
                            vf_coef=0.5,
                            max_grad_norm=0.5,
                            use_sde=False,
                            sde_sample_freq=-1,
                            target_kl=None,
                            tensorboard_log=None, 
                            policy_kwargs=None,
                            verbose=self.verbose,
                            seed=self.gym_env.random_seed,
                            device=self.device,
                            _init_setup_model=True)
        print("\n")
```

And this is my environment definition:

```
# Parameter definition (not relevant for the question)
class v1(gym.Env):
    """
    GYM functions
    """
    def __init__(self, driver, max_steps = env['NUM_ITERATIONS'], max_obs = 1000, execution = None, test_case = None, action_db = None):
        super().__init__()
        self._seed(RANDOM_SEED)

        # Move the model and data to the GPU
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            self.device = torch.device("cuda")
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()  # Clear GPU cache
        else:
            self.device = torch.device("cpu")

        # Other initializations
    
    def _get_action_space(self):
        return spaces.Discrete(len(action_set), seed = RANDOM_SEED)

    def _get_observation_space(self):
        return spaces.MultiDiscrete([(self.max_obs)] * len(self.html_tags))

    def reset(self):
        print("\t\t\t Environmet reset")
        
        return self._get_observation().to(self.device), {}

    def _get_observation(self):    
        # Iterate over each HTML tag and count the number of matching elements
        obs = []
        # Code to fill the observation

        obs = np.array(obs)
        return torch.tensor(obs, device=self.device)
```